# Plot ylim in Shiny

Tags: r, plot, shiny

I am writing an app that should produce an histogram with a slider moving the mean across children's height of a Galton's dataset (UsingR package).

The app returns an error:

```
Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'ylim' values
```

I checked for NAs, as usual. Everything is fine. Actually, there is no problem in plotting a histogram in normal conditions (without Shiny). I am new to Shiny, surely I am missing something there. A similar problem is faced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35016186/error-need-finite-ylim-values-shiny), unfortunately without solution.

The user interface file:

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
headerPanel("Example plot"),
sidebarPanel(
    sliderInput('mu', 'Guess the mean', value = 70, min = 62, max = 74, step = 0.05)
),
mainPanel(
    plot('newHist')
)
))
```

The server file:

```
library(UsingR)
data(galton)

shinyServer(
function(input, output){
    output$newHist <- renderPlot({
        hist(galton$child, xlab = 'child height', col = 'lightblue', main = 'Histogram')
            mu <- input$mu
            lines(c(mu, mu), c(0, 200), col = "red", lwd = 5)
            mse <- mean((galton$child - mu)^2)
            text(63, 150, paste("mu = ", mu))
            text(63, 140, paste("MSE = ", round(mse, 2)))
        })
}
)
```

Comment: Your problem is in UI code where you are using `plot` instead of `plotOutput`?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, now it works. Thank you very much.